# Laravel error after optimize:clear : Call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: laravel

After using  `php artisan optimize:clear`, my whole installation is broken.
Whatever the command is, it returns `Call to a member function connection() on null`.
`php artisan` alone produces the same error
`composer update` works, but ends with `php artisan package:discover --ansi` > error

Nothing has changed: all configuration files (including .env) have not changed.

Everything happens as if Laravel could not find .env

Indeed, the log lines start with `production.error`, while .env contains `APP_ENV=local`
The previous log lines always started with `local.info`, `local.error`, etc.

What happened?

Here is the complete error message:

```
[2022-09-25 05:46:09] production.ERROR: Call to a member function connection() on null {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function connection() on null at [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1734)
[stacktrace]
#0  [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1700): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::resolveConnection(NULL)
#1  [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1492): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->getConnection()
#2  [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1409): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
#3  [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1445): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->newModelQuery()
#4  [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1398): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
#5  [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2234): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->newQuery()
#6  [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2246): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->__call('where', Array)
#7  [laravel root folder]/config/site.php(33): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::__callStatic('where', Array)
#8  [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(70): require('/Library/WebSer...')
#9  [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository))
#10 [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(242): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#11 [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(375): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#12 [laravel root folder]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#13 [laravel root folder]/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#14 {main}
"}
```

Comment: Note: the config/site.php file mentioned on line 7 contains only a simple array. 
The production server, exact mirror of the local installation, still works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The end is as incomprehensible as the beginning...

The installation works again!

What I did:

1. I took my personal config file out of the /config folder
2. I called php artisan config:cache which worked
3. I put personal config file back in /config
4. New call to config:cache

... and everything is fine !

I don't understand what happened...